# Интерполяция строк es6, ошибка в gulp4

Tags: javascript, gulp, ecmascript-6

Суть проблемы такова, что при использовании интерполяции, gulp выдает ошибку следующего содержания.

GulpUglifyError: unable to minify JavaScript
Caused by: SyntaxError: Unexpected character '`'

Отсюда вытекает вопрос. Что делать с этим недоразумением? ...

За отклик буду признателен.

Answer (score 2):

Делать... прочитать ошибку.
Плагин `Uglify` не понимает новый синтаксис.
Пройдитесь `Babel` например или возьмите другой упаковщик.